# Suppress headers and footers for complete chapter

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

For my thesis, I need to include a chapter which can "stand alone", meaning it must be formatted in a way that allows the pages to be exported and be published separately.

This means, I need to get rid of the header and footer on these pages. I tried using

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

and it works as expected, but I don't want to set it manually for each page in my chapter.

Is there a way to extend this command to spread to all pages in the current section or is there another way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `\pagestyle{empty}` at the chapter start and switch back to `\pagestyle{<normalstyle>}` at the start of the next chapter. (`<normalstyle>` stands, e.g., for `headings` in the `book` class or for `fancy` if you use the [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package.)

In addition, it is necessary to set `\thispagestyle{empty}` at the chapter start in order to override the starting page's internal `plain` style.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}

\lipsum[1-12]

\chapter{blubb}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[1-12]

\chapter{foo}
\pagestyle{headings}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: perfect. I tried these two commands only separately before, but the combination works perfectly. Thank you!