# Suppress page headers in one chapter

Tags: header-footer, memoir

In a `memoir` document, how can I suppress the page headers for every page in one particular chapter?

However, I don't want want to use `\pagestyle{empty}` as recommended [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30961/9757), since I want the pages in that chapter to be formatted exactly like the other pages in the document (including having a footer, etc.)--just without the header.

Here is my current document:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Headers and Footers

\nouppercaseheads

\makepagestyle{mystyle} 
\setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
\makerunningwidth{mystyle}{\headwidth}

\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\itshape\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\itshape\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{}{\thepage}
\makepsmarks{mystyle}{\createmark{chapter}{left}{}{}{}}

\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{mystyle}{\createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{:\ }}
\makeatother

\makepagestyle{plain}
\makerunningwidth{plain}{\headwidth}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\makeatletter
\aliaspagestyle{title}{empty} % suppress the page number after \maketitle
\let\origps@chapter\ps@chapter
\preto\frontmatter{\let\ps@chapter\ps@empty\pagestyle{empty}}
\preto\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \let\ps@chapter\origps@chapter\pagestyle{mystyle}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Second Chapter}

I want to suppress the header for every page in this chapter.

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: make a new pagestyle that does the exact same thing in the footer, and just don't tell that pagestyle to do anything in the header.  I.e., use \makeoddfoot{<name>}{}{}{} and \makeevenfoot{<name>}{}{}{}, but don't use any \make*head commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `\pagestyle{plain}` immediately after `\chapter{Second Chapter}`. You don't need to add `\thispagestyle{plain}` as this is (by default) done automatically by `\chapter`. (You do modify this behaviour for `\frontmatter` in your example, but switch back to the default chapter page style for `\mainmatter`. )